# Spark save functionality use MapReduce under the hood

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I'm trying to figure out why `saveAsText` and more in general **Spark** save functionality seems to use **MapReduce** under the hood. This is the source code:

**RDD.scala**

```
  def saveAsTextFile(path: String): Unit = withScope {
    val nullWritableClassTag = implicitly[ClassTag[NullWritable]]
    val textClassTag = implicitly[ClassTag[Text]]
    val r = this.mapPartitions { iter =>
      val text = new Text()
      iter.map { x =>
        text.set(x.toString)
        (NullWritable.get(), text)
      }
    }
    RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions(r)(nullWritableClassTag, textClassTag, null)
      .saveAsHadoopFile[TextOutputFormat[NullWritable, Text]](path)
  }
```

**PairRDDFunctions.scala**

So basically convert the given RDD in a PairRDD in order to call `saveAsHadoopFile` function:

```
def saveAsHadoopFile(
      path: String,
      keyClass: Class[_],
      valueClass: Class[_],
      outputFormatClass: Class[_ <: OutputFormat[_, _]],
      conf: JobConf = new JobConf(self.context.hadoopConfiguration),
      codec: Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]] = None): Unit = self.withScope {

    val hadoopConf = conf
    hadoopConf.setOutputKeyClass(keyClass)
    hadoopConf.setOutputValueClass(valueClass)
    conf.setOutputFormat(outputFormatClass)
    for (c <- codec) {
      hadoopConf.setCompressMapOutput(true)
      hadoopConf.set("mapred.output.compress", "true")
      hadoopConf.setMapOutputCompressorClass(c)
      hadoopConf.set("mapred.output.compression.codec", c.getCanonicalName)
      hadoopConf.set("mapred.output.compression.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString)
    }

    if (conf.getOutputCommitter == null) {
      hadoopConf.setOutputCommitter(classOf[FileOutputCommitter])
    }

    val speculationEnabled = self.conf.getBoolean("spark.speculation", false)
    val outputCommitterClass = hadoopConf.get("mapred.output.committer.class", "")
    if (speculationEnabled && outputCommitterClass.contains("Direct")) {
      val warningMessage =
        s"$outputCommitterClass may be an output committer that writes data directly to " +
          "the final location. Because speculation is enabled, this output committer may " +
          "cause data loss (see the case in SPARK-10063). If possible, please use a output " +
          "committer that does not have this behavior (e.g. FileOutputCommitter)."
      logWarning(warningMessage)
    }

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(hadoopConf,
      SparkHadoopWriter.createPathFromString(path, hadoopConf))
    saveAsHadoopDataset(hadoopConf)
  }
```

For my understanding here, it definitely trying to configure a MapReduce job, setting outputKey, outputValue and so on.

Could someone explain to me:

- how Spark save operation happen
- what are the main difference between Spark save and MapReduce save

Answer (score 0):

> it definitely trying to configure a MapReduce job, setting outputKey, outputValue and so on.

Not exactly. It is setting Hadoop configuration, but it doesn't mean it is setting MapReduce job. Hadoop as such contains multiple different components, and large number of these is not tightly bound to MapReduce. Many of these, like HDFS interfaces or security components are used across many different projects.

> what are the main difference between Spark save and MapReduce save

Here none. In general when Spark interacts with file systems, it uses related Hadoop components. These however are independent of MapReduce components and shouldn't be confused with Hadoop MR jobs.